# robot_localization

Tags: navigation, ekf, odometry, mapping, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen the package has changed a lot since I used it the last time.

I have a doubt:
Is it correct the structure shown in the picture (with two map frames)?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201006/robot_localization/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2015-01-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-01-16**:
Did you post an image? I don't see one. Sorry, I don't currently have a laptop with me and am viewing this on a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I still don't see a picture, but there are three coordinate frames, all of which are specified by REP-105. See the description of the frame parameters [here](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization#Standard_Parameters).

EDIT: Just so I understand, are you trying to use AMCL *and* a GPS?

EDIT 2: Not sure how you're planning to combine AMCL and the GPS-enabled instance of `ekf_localization_node`, but here is how the data is meant to flow, at least as far as `robot_localization` is concerned:

[image: image description]

Your launch files for your two instances of `ekf_localization_node` should be very similar, except in the second one, you'll have your *world_frame* set to *map* instead of *odom*, and you'll have a new input source (the GPS odometry coming from `navsat_transform_node`).

EDIT in response to comment below: No, that's not what I meant, sorry. First, I'm guessing that `amcl` should receive the output of your *odom* instance of `ekf_localization_node`, not the *map* instance. Second, if you look at my drawing, you'll see a difference in the way the sensor data is being used. In your drawing, you are only feeding the raw odometry and IMU to *one* instance of `ekf_localization_node`. In my drawing, *both* instances work with the raw data. Don't feed the output of `ekf_localization_node`'s *odom* instance into the *map* instance.

EDIT in response to comment: Yeah, I'm aware that reparenting would be an issue. I'm advocating that he drop the GPS instance of `ekf_localization_node`. `amcl's` handling of transforms (compute *map*->*base_link*, listen for *odom*->*base_link*, use that to compute and publish *map*->*odom*) is identical to that of `robot_localization's` state estimation nodes when `world_frame` == `map_frame`.

In any case, the setup should work as-is (provided the sensor data is fed into the *map1* instance of `ekf_localization_node`), yes. However, I don't know if there are any implications within `amcl` if the *map1*->*base_link* transform has any discontinuities. Perhaps there are none.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2015-01-16**:
I Know it.
Maybe you can see the picture with its link
http://s18.postimg.org/ig947a8d4/robot.jpg

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2015-01-21**:
I have changed the image.
I am trying to do exactly what you've said, but the amcl from ros uses the out put of ekf to work. Because of that  I have draw the diagram in the question

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2015-01-27**:
Actually, AMCL computes the localization on base_link, and then publishes the transformation between that localization (in the frame `global_frame_id`) and wathever frame is passed as `odom_frame_id`. I guess that using `/map1` as `odom_frame_id` is correct, otherwise `/odom` would have two parents.